# Inserting linebreak in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm building a XSL to read the values of a XML with multiple tags.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Playlist>
  <CLIPNAME>CC0001</CLIPNAME>
  <CLIPNAME>CC0002</CLIPNAME>
</Playlist>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" xmlns:XslUtils="java:com.dalet.ip.XslUtils">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:output name="serializer" method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<Titles>
    <Title>
    <xsl:for-each select="Playlist/CLIPNAME">
        <key1><xsl:value-of select="."/></key1>
        <OnAir>Yes</OnAir>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </Title>
</Titles>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I already tried multiple options that i saw online:

```
<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>


<xsl:text>
```

with $newline, etc

The current output is:

```
CC0001 Yes CC0002 Yes
```

And I want it to be:

```
CC0001 Yes
CC0002 Yes
```

What can I do?

Comment: The output from that stylesheet should be indented already judging by the `<xsl:output>` definition.

Comment: should I change the parameters so i can have multiple lines?

Comment: The stylesheet you've shown and the output you claim to be getting are inconsistent - the output of that stylesheet should be XML (with nice indentation already, due to the `xsl:output` settings), not plain text.

Comment: I'm using the "Try it" of W3CSchools, and the output that i get is that one.

Comment: [w3schools has nothing to do with the W3C](http://www.w3fools.com), and their "try it" tool just uses your browser's built-in XSLT 1.0 processor and lets the browser render the results as it sees fit.  If you want to test your stylesheets properly then use something like [xsltransform.net](http://xsltransform.net/948Fn5o) which (a) supports XSLT 2.0 and (b) lets you see the actual XML produced by your transformation, rather than just your browser's interpretation of it.

Comment: @IanRoberts, agreed, although, to be fair (and out of unrelated interest), are you aware of cases where browsers exercise liberty in their "interpretation" of at least XSLT 1.0?  I haven't had any problems.

Comment: @harpo I meant that what you see in the output pane is the browser's rendering of whatever XML your transformation produced.  If the output is HTML then that's fine, but if it's XML then typically a browser will render an XML element it doesn't recognise as if it were an HTML `<span>` and all you see is therefore the text node descendants.

Comment: @harpo also, there are [specific instructions in the XSLT spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#forwards) about how processors must behave when you give them a stylesheet that declares its version number as something more recent than the processor supports.  A 1.0 processor will not necessarily fail if you give it a 2.0 stylesheet, but it probably won't process it in the way a 2.0 processor would do.

Answer (score 0):

Add a text tag containing a linebreak. Not very elegant but works for me.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Playlist/CLIPNAME">
    <key1><xsl:value-of select="."/></key1>
    <OnAir>Yes</OnAir>
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```